# Picking up a for loop at a certain index (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

During a simulation using a `for` loop, the system crashed. Each loop's results were saved and I want to pick up the simulation again at the point it crashed. I know the index `i,j` at which it crashed in a loop of the form:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:5){
    ...
  }
}
```

Let's suppose the previous loop crashed at `i=2, j=3`. Clearly I cannot use `for(j in 3:5)` in the inner loop, as subsequent loops over `i` would then not start at `j=1`. What are options to pick up the loops at the correct index?

Comment: In the inner loop just check if result for (i,j) is already there, if yes then `break` the loop other wise continue.

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful to have `tryCatch` and return NA or something

Comment: @akrun You mean to prevent the crash? Yes, but the crash was caused externally to `R`....

Comment: yes, i meant that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
for (i in 2:5) {
    start <- ifelse(i == 2, 3, 1)
    for (j in start:5) {
        # do something
    }
}
```

For the outermost loop it should be OK to hard code a value of `i=2`, since the `i=1` iteration is known to have run completely.  For the inner loop, you may conditionally choose between a starting value of `j=3`, which happens when `i=2`, otherwise choosing `j=1` as the start of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:5){
    trycatch({
      # Do Something
    },error = function(err){
      # error handling or debug with e.g. 'browser()'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This prevents the crash (internally; not if causes are external); my question assumes the crash already occured.